# Is it possible to deploy an app that I coded for Android to iOS?

Tags: javascript, android, xml

I'm using Eclipse to build my Android app using XML and JavaScript. Is it possible to deploy it to the App store without rewriting all the code?

Answer (score 1):

If you have coded your app to be substantially made up of a webview, then you can transfer all that part of the code over by several methods - the one that I think would be easiest would be phonegap.

In the future, you can think about using Titanium Studio which allows you to code in Javascript (and a tiny bit of XML for configuration) and compiles to native code for both Android and iOS - so has native performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you written your app in something like Sencha or PhoneGap - then you can run that code on every platform these frameworks support. But it's in Java (not JavaScript), then there's no way run it on iOS I'm afraid.